# Dynamic components in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

My problem: there are too many components in the `components` folders.
How can I dynamically access some components from a component array defined in the `app.vue` page?

How can I show the components I specified in the array on the `app.vue` page? I want to select from the array of components on the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with dynamic components in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029628/working-with-dynamic-components-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code:

```js
Vue.component('tab-home', { 
    template: '<div>Home component</div>' 
})
Vue.component('tab-posts', { 
    template: '<div>Posts component</div>' 
})
Vue.component('tab-archive', { 
    template: '<div>Archive component</div>' 
})

new Vue({
  el: '#dynamic-component-demo',
  data: {
    currentTab: 'Home',
    tabs: ['Home', 'Posts', 'Archive']
  },
  computed: {
    currentTabComponent: function () {
      return 'tab-' + this.currentTab.toLowerCase()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tab-button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.tab-button:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.tab-button.active {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="dynamic-component-demo" class="demo">
  <button
    v-for="tab in tabs"
    v-bind:key="tab"
    v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
    v-on:click="currentTab = tab"
  >{{ tab }}</button>

  <component
    v-bind:is="currentTabComponent"
    class="tab"
  ></component>
</div>
```